# use onclick with action in h:commandbutton

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, commandbutton

i want select a user and edit it in pop-up page.

```
   <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="friendselected" value="#{userBean.selecteduser}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.users}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton value="Edit User" action="#{userBean.edituser()}" onclick="#{userBean.JSPopup()}" />
    </h:form>
```

pop-up code

```
public String JSPopup() {
    return "javascript:void window.open(' UserEdit.xhtml ',' name ','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;";
}
```

First i will select user and set it's id to selecteduser. After in pop-up page i see it's informatin in  and edit.

```
public void edituser()
{
    initializeJdbc();

    String aSQL="select * from users where UserID="+selecteduser;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        st = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(aSQL);

        if(rs.next()) {
            fullname=rs.getString("FullName");
            username=rs.getString("UserName");
            password=rs.getString("Password");
            gender=rs.getString("Gender").charAt(0);
            BirthDate=rs.getString("BirthDate");
            Tel=rs.getString("Tel");
            Email=rs.getString("Email");
            Address=rs.getString("Address");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any questions...

Comment: button doesn't work. only onclick working in commandButton but don't work wiyh action. How can i work onclick and action together?

Answer (score 0):

The `return false;` in your `userBean.JSPopup()` means that you the default event should not be started, so your action is never called. Remove it and it should be fine.

Another hint, not causing problems for you at the moment, but worth noting. The *onclick* is a value attribute, so when you place a method expression within, it will not call the method bean onclick, rather it will call it immediately when page is rendered (simply set a debug in your JSPopup method, to see this). If I were you, I would replace the method expression with the js code e.g.

```
onclick="javascript:void window.open(' UserEdit.xhtml ',' name ','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');"
```

or create a function and call it from onclick. At present your not getting any issue, as the method is returning js code only, but in future, if you add additional logic to the method, you might get unexpected results.